# How to update a `data.table` within `foreach` by reference

Tags: r, data.table, parallel-foreach

I read a large `.csv` file into a `data.table` using `fread`. In a next step, I conduct some data cleaning operations such as converting some character variables to dates.

## Memory optimized solution

Here is my memory optimized solution in a MWE:

```
library(data.table)
library(foreach)

dt <- data.table(chr_date_1 = c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03"),
                 chr_date_2 = c("2017-01-04", "2017-01-05", "2017-01-06"))

for (date_var in c("chr_date_1", "chr_date_2")) {
  dt %>% 
    set(j = date_var, value = ymd(.[[date_var]]))
}
```

## Speed optimized solution?

Since there are 8.5 million observations and ~30 variables which should be manipulated in some way I was wondering if this could be optimized in terms of speed using `foreach`. (I run R on a Virtual Client with 128GB RAM, so memory is not the primary concern.) My first attempt looked like this:

```
registerDoParallel(cores=7)

foreach (date_var = names(dt), .packages = c("data.table")) %dopar% {
  set(dt, j = date_var, value = as.Date(dt[[date_var]]))
}
```

Unfortunately, this only prints the results in the console instead of updating `dt`:

```
[[1]]
chr_date_1 chr_date_2
1: 2017-01-01 2017-01-04
2: 2017-01-02 2017-01-05
3: 2017-01-03 2017-01-06

[[2]]
chr_date_1 chr_date_2
1: 2017-01-01 2017-01-04
2: 2017-01-02 2017-01-05
3: 2017-01-03 2017-01-06
```

Next, I tried to set up `.combine` and `.init`, ...

```
foreach (date_var = names(dt), .packages = c("data.table"),
         .combine = "cbind", .init = dt) %dopar% {
           set(dt, j = date_var, value = as.Date(dt[[date_var]]))
         }
```

... but there were new columns added instead of existing ones updated:

```
  chr_date_1 chr_date_2 chr_date_1 chr_date_2 chr_date_1 chr_date_2
  1: 2017-01-01 2017-01-04 2017-01-01 2017-01-04 2017-01-01 2017-01-04
  2: 2017-01-02 2017-01-05 2017-01-02 2017-01-05 2017-01-02 2017-01-05
  3: 2017-01-03 2017-01-06 2017-01-03 2017-01-06 2017-01-03 2017-01-06
```

So, is it possible at all to update several columns of a `data.table` in parallel using `foreach`?

If not, might there be a solution in which I create all new columns in parallel and the somehow merge them into the existing `data.table`? One aspect which prevented me from elaborating on this is the fact that the last `foreach` snipped yields the same (*4 columns*) when I omit `.init = dt`.

---

## EDIT:

I found a way of getting the desired result, but in an example with 7 variables (= number of registered cores) and 3M observations, this took approximately 5 times longer than the *memory optimized solution*. So just for telling you, how *not* to do it:

```
result <- foreach (date_var = names(dt), .packages = c("data.table")) %dopar% {
    dt[, (date_var) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), .SDcols = date_var]
  } %>% .[[length(.)]]
```

Also, the needed amount of memory is insane.

Comment: No, that's not possible. However, depending on your date format there are faster date parsers available in packages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247063/is-there-a-fast-parser-for-date

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Roland. I was actually using `lubridate` due to convenience but replaced it in the MWE for simplicity. Your post made me aware of the fact that `ymd` is even (way!) slower than `as.Date`.

Comment: You are just parallelizing by columns? I imagine there's some `DT[, (cols) := mclapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols=cols]` or similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, I run R on Windows here at work, so I can't increase `mc.cores`. Therefore, `mclapply` is slightly slower than the _memory optimized solution_ I described in my question. Anyway, thanks for the hint, I will try that at home on a linux machine.