# Fastest way to parse a date-time string to class Date

Tags: r, date, datetime, as.date

I have a column with dates as character in the format `10/17/2017 12:00:00 AM`. I want parse the string and keep only the date part as class `Date`, i.e. `2017-10-17`. I am using -

```
df$ReportDate = as.Date(df$ReportDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") 
df$ReportDate = as.Date(format(df$ReportDate, "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

this works, but the dataframe has over 5 million rows so this takes close to two mins.

```
  user  system elapsed 
104.73    0.55  105.46
```

Is there a faster and more efficient way to do this?

Comment: An excel file has over 5M rows? I am guessing its a csv file. try using `fread` from `datatable` package

Comment: Sorry I think my question was unclear. It is not the reading process that takes time but just the date conversion process. Will edit.

Comment: Is this for computations or for reporting. Your two lines of code return equivalent vectors, at least for me. `df <- rep("8/31/2017 12:30:00 pm", 5e6);
df <- as.Date(df, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p");
df1 <- as.Date(format(df, "%Y-%m-%d"));
all(df == df1)`

Comment: You could use `substr` to extract only the date part - leave the time behind - and then use `as.Date(df$ReportDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y)` might be faster without parsing the time as well - I'm not sure. I'm also not sure why you are using `as.Date` twice. Isn't once enough?

Comment: Sorry, why dont you try using `strptime`

Comment: I'd also suggest a dupe: [Is there a fast parser for Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35247063/903061). The answer there suggests a roughly 2x speedup using the `fasttime` package.

Comment: `as.Date("10/17/2017 12:00:00 AM", format = "%m/%d/%Y")` is enough. "_Each input string is processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing characters are ignored._"

Comment: @Gregor I use as.Date twice because the dates are originally stored in character type (the dataframe is imported using fread). So the first conversion converts to date object. I then extract the date using `format`, which converts the type back to character. Since I need it as a date object for further operations, I use as.Date a second time to convert to date object.

Comment: @Henrik That works! And it takes 4 seconds, so about 25x faster. If you post as answer, I will accept.

Comment: The second conversion is redundant. As you say, the first conversion converts to a Date object. The exact same Date object that your second line converts to.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Note that `as.Date` will ignore junk after the date so this takes less than 10 seconds on my not particularly fast laptop:

```
xx <- rep("10/17/2017 12:00:00 AM", 5000000) # test input
system.time(as.Date(xx, "%m/%d/%Y"))
## user  system elapsed 
## 9.57    0.20    9.82
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be more efficient to convert from `Date` to `character`:

```
# Create dummy data
date_from <- as.Date('01/01/1999  12:00:00 AM',
    format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

date_to <- as.Date('01/01/2017  12:00:00 AM',
    format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

df <- data.frame(ReportDate = sample(seq(from = date_from,
    to = date_to, by = "day"), 5000000, T))

# Convert to char
start <- Sys.time()
df$ReportDate <- as.character(df$ReportDate)

Sys.time() - start
Time difference of 12.37254 secs

head(df)
  ReportDate
1 2011-08-04
2 2013-11-15
3 2002-09-08
4 2011-07-01
5 2011-01-22
6 2001-01-04
```

Comment: I need to keep it as `Date` for further operations hence the final conversion using `as.Date()`

Comment: I see, that was not entirely clear from the question. I had overlooked that you initially have the data stored as `character` and not `Date`, so it makes sense to use @Henriks solution.